# Make a colorful table

Tags: code-golf, generation

For this challenge, you must accept input as a comma-separated list (columns) of a run (rows) of the first letters of any of the colors `red`, `orange`, `yellow`, `green`, `blue`, or `purple`, and output (to stdout) the HTML for a table of those colors.

This is fairly hard to understand, so I'll just give a simple example.

Input:

```
rgb,gbr,grb
```

Output (with example screenshot):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: red" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: green" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: blue" width="50" height="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: green" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: blue" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: red" width="50" height="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: green" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: red" width="50" height="50"></td>
          <td style="background-color: blue" width="50" height="50"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Note that the HTML you output need not be valid; it just has to work. By "work", I mean that your output will be pasted into a `.html` file and viewed in the latest (currently, 9/28/13) Chrome (v 29.0.1547.76). The squares must be 50 pixels width and height. You may have whatever padding between them as you want (Chrome automatically uses 1 pixel of padding, even when you specify `padding: 0px`, so I can't control that).

Input will always be valid (letters will be one of `roygbp`), but the rows are not guaranteed to have equal amounts of squares in them. For example, `roygbp,ooo` is valid and should output

[image: image 2]

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins.

Comment: Table layouts >:(

Comment: @minitech They're not layouts :P and anything goes in code golf :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Perl: <s>153</s> <s>126</s> <s>124</s> <s>116</s> 114 characters

```perl
s!\w!'<td bgcolor=#'.substr(ff00f90707,yrbxoxgp=~$&&&@-[0],3).' width=50 height=50>'!ge;s!,!<tr>!g;$_="<table>$_"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -p table.pl <<< 'rgb,oyp'
<table><td bgcolor=#f00 width=50 height=50><td bgcolor=#070 width=50 height=50><td bgcolor=#00f width=50 height=50><tr><td bgcolor=#f90 width=50 height=50><td bgcolor=#ff0 width=50 height=50><td bgcolor=#707 width=50 height=50>
```

Sample output:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -p table.pl <<< 'yrryyryyryyyrrr,ryyyryryryyyryy,ryryryryryyyrry,yrryyryyrrryryy'
```

[image: colorful table sample output]

Answer (score 4):

### Razor Leaf, 136

```
table for r in prompt().split(",")
    tr for x in r
        td bgcolor:"##{"rf00of90yff0g070b00fp707".match(x+"(...)")[1]}"width:"50"height:"50"
```

[Razor Leaf](https://github.com/charmander/razorleaf). The indentation is tabs, by the way.

You might have some trouble running this in a browser, so try Node.js and define `global.prompt` to return a fixed output. :)

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var razorleaf = require("razorleaf");

global.prompt = function() {
    return "rgb,byp";
};

console.log(razorleaf.compile(fs.readFileSync("test.leaf", "utf-8"))());
```

Using other people’s tricks is 126, but that’s no good.

```
table cellpadding:"26"for r in prompt().split(",")
    tr for x in r
        td bgcolor:"##{"rf00rof90oyff0yg070gb00fbp707".split(x)[1]}"
```

Comment: ooh, interesting language! I'm going to look in to that :D

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>148</s> 139

```
d_~f~n_:=Export[n,Grid@ToExpression@Characters@d/.{r->Red,o->Orange,y->Yellow,g->Green,
b->Blue,p->Purple}/.{x_RGBColor:>Graphics@{x,Rectangle[]}}]
```

---

`f`, defined above, is a simple function that takes the color strings as input and outputs an HTML file.

**Usage**

```
f[{"rgb","gbr","grb"}, "ColorfulTable.html"]
```

The HTML code that is output to file "ColorfulTable.html":

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< ! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN"
"HTMLFiles/xhtml-math11-f.dtd" >
< ! --Created by Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 : www.wolfram.com-- >
< html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
< head >
< title > Untitled
< /title >
< link href = "HTMLFiles/ColorfulTable.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"/ >
 < /head >
 < body >
 < p class = "Output" >
  < img src = "HTMLFiles/ColorfulTable.gif" alt = "ColorfulTable.gif" width = "360" height = "360"   
   style = "vertical-align:middle"/ >
       < /p >
       < div style = "font-family:Helvetica; font-size:11px; width:100%; border:1px none #999999; border-top-style:solid; padding-top:2px; margin-top:20px;" >
        < a href = "http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/" style = "color:#000; text-decoration:none;" >
          < img src = "HTMLFiles/spikeyIcon.png" alt = "Spikey" width = "20" height = "21" style = "padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;"/ >
               < span style = "color:#555555" > Created with < /span > Wolfram < span style = "font-style: italic;" > Mathematica < /span > 9.0
< /a >
< /div >
< /body >
< /html >
```

**HTML rendering in Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Hmm... this is stretching the rules a lot... input is very different from specified and it outputs to a file, not stdout. I'm afraid that this breaks too many rules, but very creative :D (oh, and btw I count 171 chars)

Comment: too bad. In principal, I ought to be able to input the HTML as a string, leaving it in standard output. But I haven't figured out how to do it yet. The byte count seems to be correct. I used the automatic-counter from Wolfram's One-Liner Competition.  The spaces are by and large optional. And `:>` is a single character in Mathematica.

Comment: lettercount.com says 147 for the current code? Missed to update it ?

Comment: `->` and `:>` are single characters in Mathematica. And <newline> is included only for readability.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>203</s> 146

```
for(h='<table cellpadding=26>',p=prompt(),i=0;c=p[i++];)
h+=","==c?"<tr>":'<td bgcolor=#'+'rF00roFA0oyFF0yg080gb00Fbp808'.split(c)[1]+'>';
alert(h)
```

Credit to @C5H8NNaO4 for the single loop & cellpadding ideas. I'm using a split string to find the right color. (the line breaks were added for readability)

Input:

```
rgb,bgroyp
```

Output:

```
<table cellpadding=26><td bgcolor=#F00><td bgcolor=#080><td bgcolor=#00F><tr><td bgcolor=#00F><td bgcolor=#080><td bgcolor=#F00><td bgcolor=#FA0><td bgcolor=#FF0><td bgcolor=#808>
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33qpU/4/)

Does anyone know how to use unicode characters in JSFiddle? I could shave a few more characters off, but some characters wouldn't paste in correctly.

Comment: Nice improvement, especially the colorfinding =)

Comment: wait did you just copy mine,replaced the color object and moved 2 vars inside the for ? =P +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript, <s>154</s> <s>144</s> 119

```
'<table><tr>'\{:^44='<tr>'{"<td bgcolor="['red''orange''yellow''green''blue''purple']{0=^=}?" width=50 height=50>"}if}%
```

[Online test](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJyZ2IsZ2JyLGdyYiIKJzx0YWJsZT48dHI%2BJ1x7Ol40ND0nPHRyPid7Ijx0ZCBiZ2NvbG9yPSJbJ3JlZCcnb3JhbmdlJyd5ZWxsb3cnJ2dyZWVuJydibHVlJydwdXJwbGUnXXswPV49fT8iIHdpZHRoPTUwIGhlaWdodD01MD4ifWlmfSU%3D)

With credit to @bendytree for introducing the no-close-tags trend which allowed me to cut 25 chars.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (158)

```
print('<table>',*['<tr>'+''.join('<td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=#%03x>'%dict(r=3840,o=3984,y=4080,g=96,b=15,p=1799)[c]for c in r)for r in input().split(',')])
```

Cool things:

- This uses the `*` operator to pass multiple arguments to `print`, saving 6  characters compared to `''.join`.
- The colors are stored in decimal, then rendered as hex in the HTML. I found this to be much shorter than using string literals directly.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <del>199</del> <del>183</del> <del>173</del> <del>171</del> <del>167</del>  <del>164</del> <del>159</del> <del>158</del> 154

```
h="<table cellpadding=26>";p=prompt();for(i=0;c=p[i++];)h+=","==c?"<tr>":'<td bgcolor=#'+{r:"F00",o:"FA0",y:"FF0",g:"080",b:"00F",p:"808"}[c]+'>';alert(h)
```

<sub>*just realized i don't need an opening `<tr>` tag*

*stupid me, i of course do **not** need to split the input string to access single chars*

*... as well as i of course do not need to initialise `c`*

*inlined the lookup object*

*you can actually leave out the px for width and height*

*changed width and height to cellpadding 26px*

*replaced `</tr>` with `<tr>`*
*removed the `'` around 26 at the cellpadding and from the bgcolor*</sub>

*Changin the `for` to a `for .. in` loop would save only one character, so i keep the for*

[Example Output](http://jsfiddle.net/CcQEz/5) for `roygbp,ooo`

```
<table cellpadding=26><td bgcolor=#F00><td bgcolor=#FA0><td bgcolor=#FF0><td bgcolor=#080><td bgcolor=#00F><td bgcolor=#808><tr><td bgcolor=#FA0><td bgcolor=#FA0><td bgcolor=#FA0>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6: 148 characters

```javascript
alert('<table>'+prompt().replace(/./g,x=>x==','?'<tr>':'<td bgcolor='+'red green orange yellow blue purple'.match(x+'\\w+')+' width=50 height=50>'))
```

(Just to exercise the fat arrow syntax.)

Comment: Could you name your language ECMAScript 6? As the latest firefox is currently the only browser supporting it, it would avoid confusion

Comment: Ok. And thanks for the information. (Sadly I had no time to test in other browsers. But one thing is sure: in Firefox is available since [version 22](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/22), not only the latest. ;))

Comment: =) Thanks, ( I would love seeing chrome supporting ES6 soon). Well yeah :P "latest" is the wrong word here, I'm not using firefox and am not up to date with their versions. So i think "the newer firefox browsers" would have been more appropriate. Nice use of the regex engine to create the complete table! +1

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <del>182</del> <del>164</del> 163 characters

Example input:

```
<?php $x = 'roygbp,ooo'; ?>
```

*Update 1; if you silence (or just ignore) E_NOTICE you can remove the quotes around strings that start with letters, shaving off another 18 characters*

*Update 2; trimmed 1 character!*

```
<?php echo'<table cellpadding=50><tr>';$a=[r=>f00,g=>'080',b=>blue,o=>fa0,p=>'808',y=>ff0];foreach(str_split($x)as$b){echo$b==','?'<tr>':"<td bgcolor=#$a[$b]>";}?>
```

Comment: You could change `b=>'00f'` to `b=>blue` to save 1 character, and remove `cellpadding=50` to save 15.

Comment: @Doorknob Nice catch, but removing the cellpadding would make the boxes 2px x 2px; wouldn't that be cheating out of the assignment specification?

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, <s>221</s> 187

I am presenting my own solution first, as always:

```
$><<'<table>'+gets.chop.split(?,).map{|r|'<tr>'+r.chars.map{|t|"<td bgcolor=#{'red green orange yellow blue purple'.match(t+'\w+')[0]} width=50 height=50></td>"}*''+'</tr>'}*''+'</table>'
```

Comment: That can be reduced to 187 with some simple tricks: `$><<'<table>'+gets.chop.split(?,).map{|r|'<tr>'+r.chars.map{|t|"<td bgcolor=#{'red green orange yellow blue purple'.match(t+'\w+')[0]} width=50 height=50></td>"}*''+'</tr>'}*''+'</table>'`.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 277 characters

```
<style>div div{display:inline-block;width:50px;height:50px}<?foreach(array(red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple)as$c){echo".$c[0]{background-color:$c}";}?></style><?foreach(split(",",fgets(STDIN))as$r){?><div><?foreach(str_split($r)as$c)echo"<div class='$c'></div>"?></div><?}?>
```

Input:

```
rgb,bgr,gbr
```

Output:

```
<style>div div{display:inline-block;width:50px;height:50px}.r{background-color:red}.o{background-color:orange}.y{background-color:yellow}.g{background-color:green}.b{background-color:blue}.p{background-color:purple}</style><div><div class='r'></div><div class='g'></div><div class='b'></div></div><div><div class='b'></div><div class='g'></div><div class='r'></div></div><div><div class='g'></div><div class='b'></div><div class='r'></div></div>
```

Hmmm... the stylesheet is killing me here. I don't have time now, but I'll come back to have a look at this later.

And yes, I'm deliberately not using tables for layout. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7 (176)

```
I=raw_input().split(",")
h="<table>"
c=dict(r=3840,o=3984,y=4080,g=96,b=15,p=1799)
for r in I:
 h+="<tr>"
 for x in r:h+="<td width=50 height=50 bgcolor='#%03x'>"%c[x]
print h
```

I pinched the use of dict and the insertion of Hex values from @Lambda Fairy

And for good measure, here is a [jsfiddle with an example output](http://jsfiddle.net/WZkwM/)